# flex multiple array collections with a single datasource

Tags: apache-flex

How can I populate multiple datagrids in flex with a single datasource that is filtered differently for each datagrid.  I'm assigning the event.result from my remote object call to three different array collections, each with its own filter function.  When I assign and refresh the filter functions, they each affect all array collections.  So, the results of the last array collection refresh end up in all three datagrids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use [ObjectUtil](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html).copy on your event result to have 3 separate ArrayCollections, one for each DataGrid... otherwise they all point at the same memory location of the single ArrayCollection and any changes made to it will be reflected in all DataGrids.

```
var AC1:ArrayCollection = event.result as ArrayCollection;
var AC2:ArrayCollection = ObjectUtil.copy(AC1) as ArrayCollection;
var AC3:ArrayCollection = ObjectUtil.copy(AC1) as ArrayCollection;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would make copies of your data provider, ie:

```
var myDataArray:Array; // this contains your original data.

dataGrid1.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(myDataArray.concat()); 

dataGrid2.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(myDataArray.concat());

dataGrid3.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(myDataArray.concat());
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions that have been provided may not behave as you might wish they would. An ArrayCollection technically consists of a model and a "view" into the model.  In my understanding, both the solutions that have been provided create a copy of the model.  This means if you add an item to one ArrayCollection it won't show up in another regardless of whether it would match that ArrayCollection's filter.  *Usually* you want it to be a part of the model of the other ArrayCollections as well but only be visible if the added item passes the respective ArrayCollection's filter.  You can share the "model" amongst ArrayCollections while having separate views into the model like so:

```
var collection1:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

var collection2:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
collection2.list = collection1.list;

var collection3:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
collection3.list = collection1.list;
```

Now you can add an item to any of the three collections and it will show up in the others.  However, you can have separate filters and sorts on each individual ArrayCollection and that won't affect what's viewable in the others.  You can read more about this here:

http://aaronhardy.com/flex/collections-and-chaining-for-separate-presentation/